# Boxplot & Scatter Plot: Disappearing X Ticks

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I have some data to make a scatter plot:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'X':[3,3,3,3],
                     'Y':[1,2,3,4]})
```

and some more data to make a box plot on the same axes:

```
np.random.seed(1234)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,1),
                   columns=['Y'])

df_2['X'] = [2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2]
```

I tried:

```
# Scatter
ax = df_1.plot.scatter(x='X',
                       y='Y',
                       c='k',
                       s=100)

props = dict(linewidth=4)

# Boxplot
ax = df_2.boxplot(by='X',
                  boxprops     = props,
                  medianprops  = props,
                  whiskerprops = props,
                  capprops     = props,
                  ax=ax)

plt.suptitle("")
ax.set_title("")
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')

font = {'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 30}
plt.rc('font', **font)

plt.xlim([0,4])

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(10,7)

plt.show()
```

but I got:

[image]

My x axis doesn't show all it's ticks and the ones that it does show are in the wrong place. How can I correct the x axis please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried:

```
plt.xticks([0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4])
```

Which gave me:

[image]

This has corrected the x axis but the box plots are still in the wrong position along it.